# Many-To-One hibernate delete the many when delete the one?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have two classes

```
Account
id.
....

Invoice
id...
....
account_id (many to one)
```

As many invoices exist for one user, and it requires a User, I wrote it as many to one in invoice.
Cascading I believe means if I delete an Invoice then it will affect the account, by trying to add update/delete etc.

However to delete an account there are foreign key which means it cannot be deleted, unless I remove all invoices first.

A workaround is having a one to many/joining table in account, but I would rather have many to one as a invoice requires an account.

Is there a setting i could put in the orm to mean:
If I delete a Invoice nothing happens to account.
If I delete an account ALL the invoices linked to it are deleted

currently::

```
  <many-to-one name="account" fetch="EAGER" 
               target-entity="UserAccount">
      <join-column name="account_id"/>
      <cascade><cascade-all/></cascade>
  </many-to-one>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Map a OneToMany in Account to Invoice.  You are mistaken when you thought it needed a join table - it does not.  Based on you wanting to have a Invoice->Account ManyToOne relationship, you can just reuse this relationship:

```
@Entity
Class Account {
  @OneToMany(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="account")
  List<Invoice> invoices;
}

@Entity
Class Invoice{
  @ManyToOne
  Account account;
}
```

These settings mean the if you delete an Account, JPA will delete all referenced invoices as well.  Since there are no cascade settings on the Invoice.account relation, deleting an Invoice does not affect the account.  That said, you should remove the invoice from the Account.invoice collection when you are deleting an invoice instance.  JPA does not maintain bidirectional relationships for you, so when you modify one side of a bidirectional relationhip, you are required to modify the other side as well to keep your object model in sync with the database - JPA allows for caching which won't reflect the database if you don't.

There are many tutorials you could look at for this relationship, but the simplest explaination I've found is:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Relationship_Mappings/Collection_Mappings/OneToMany

If you don't want it to be Bidirectional (ie you don't want the Invoice.account reference), I believe JPA 2.0 allows you to use a @JoinColumn annotation on the OneToMany:

```
@Entity
Class Account {
  @OneToMany(cascade=ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="account_id")
  List<Invoice> invoices;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I can suggest is to set cascading delete in the foreign key relationship in the database. That way when an account is deleted all the related invoices will be deleted easily.